# iOS Auto Resizable Container Views

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, storyboard, ios-autolayout, uicontainerview

I am building an iOS app with multiple screens but I want avoid duplication of code as well as one large storyboard. Ideally I would like to load the various View Controllers based on a selected storyboard in my content view when needed.

The template of the screen (Master/Root View) shall be composed by 3 Views, namely:

- **View A** that acts as a Navigation View,
- **View B** where the various View Controllers should be loaded based on user actions and,
- **View C**, much like a Tab bar or a 3rd View where I can display some
  circumstantial information.

[image]

Now, of course I could go with a traditional UINavigationController and UITabBar but I need greater control over those views, notably in terms of size (they have minimum heights that are larger than the ones for NavBar and TabBar).

I also need those Views to resize based on the Traits and Class Size to keep filling the entire screen.

I am trying to use container views to doing so, but I can't get them to resize automatically despite having tried a different set of constraints in auto-layout. Putting the 3 views in a stackview does not do the trick either.

Ultimately I would like to be able to work separately on my various Controller Views that will be loaded in **View B**, using their own storyboards, calling them programmatically in B and having everything automatically resized.

[image]

Thank you all for your kind and valuable input!
Chris

Comment: A good start here would be having a look at writing your own [container view controller](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ImplementingaContainerViewController.html). This would allow you to keep your content view controllers separated out into separate storyboards as well as having a custom navigation and tab view.

Comment: If you expect, that containers will resize themselves according to the content size - this is not how they work. You should do it manually.

Comment: @Marcus Thanks. I have already started to look at it.

Comment: @Kelin, that's indeed what I want. At least that they can resize according to the screen size.

Comment: @Chris - are you unable to get the *container views* to change size? Or unable to get the *content* of the container views to change size?

Comment: @DonMag the content. The container changes size with the constraints.

Comment: @Chris - when you change the content in the center container view, I assume you're using `addChildViewController()`? and then adding the child VC's view as a subview of the center container view? If so, you also need to add constraints (or frame + resizing mask) to that subview.

Comment: @DonMag yes :), and the correct view in SWIFT 4 is just addChild(viewController). I think I have found a solution that works. I  load the VC in the ContentView using addChild indeed and I manipulate the auto-layout programmatically so it autosizes correctly!

Comment: @Chris - yeah, syntax change from Swift 4.1 to 4.2. I added an answer (for others who may come across this question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `addChildViewController(childVC)` / `addChild(childVC)` (*Swift 4.1 / 4.2*), followed by `myContainerView.addSubview(childVC.view)` you need to either

- add constraints for the added subview

or

- set the frame of the subview and `.autoResizingMask`

After that, your newly added subview will layout and resize correctly.

Comment: Thats basically the method! Thanks :)